# Code::blocks not detecting Ogre header file?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ogre3d

I'm still pretty new to c++ and have just flowed [these steps](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+CodeBlocks) to set up Ogre 3D. everything seemed to be working, but when i went to build my code, i got an error: `fatal error: OgreCamera.h: No such file or directory`. after going through and reviewing, i find nothing. My OGRE_HOME has the correct path and my project build options search directories for my compiler includes:

```
$(OGRE_HOME)\include
$(OGRE_HOME)\include\OGRE
$(OGRE_HOME)\include\OIS
$(OGRE_HOME)\boost
```

I cant seem to figure out why i am getting this problem and all the results i found just told me to fix these two things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In codeblocks you want to goto your build options, then from there click on your project name. After that click on search directories, click add then add all 4 of your include paths.